# LLVM: Disable some instructions while generating machine code

Tags: clang, llvm

I do not want to use particular machine instruction in my generated assembly code by llvm.

Is there way to disable the same? I'm ok with modifying the llvm code also.

Comment: What is the instruction you don't want to use, and why don't you want to use it?

Comment: It for some research purpose. I want to disable bt (bit test) instructions.

Comment: You could start by removing the bit test instructions from lib/target/X86/X86InstrInfo.td and re-building. I'm not sure if anything else would be required.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to specify to llvm that this instruction cannot be "lowered"... Two things may happen:

- the compiler can perform the same operation with another combination of instructions... things will be okay
- the compiler cannot do without it, in which case you have to modify the target generator to suggest a workaround (not quite easy if you're not familiar with llvm)

To do that search for ***XXXISelDAGToDAG.cpp***, where *XXX* is your target machine and specify to the constructor something like:

```
setOperationAction(ISD::YYY, MVT::i8, Expand);
setOperationAction(ISD::YYY, MVT::i16, Expand);
setOperationAction(ISD::YYY, MVT::i32, Expand);
setOperationAction(ISD::YYY, MVT::i64, Expand);
```

Where *ISD::YYY* is the instruction you don't want to use.
This is quite easy to locate when browsing the source code.

Roughly:

- *setOperationAction* specifies that you want to change the default action for a given operation, along with the type (MVT::...)
- *Expand* means "try to expand to another operation" (there are other actions, such as *Custom*, *Libcall*...)

Playing around with that, you should be able to solve your problem.

Hoping it will help.